# Is "You are the one who I want to be with" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

I saw a quote on the internet:

> "If someone asks me *who I want to be with*, I would simply say".

If I use a part of this sentence and put words like this:

> "You are the one *who I want to be with*."

Will it be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited the answer:

Yes, this is correct.

As you can see from the comments, some people insist on using **whom** instead of **who** and they are right from the formal English grammar point of view. However, using **who** in your particular sentence is acceptable and, in my opinion, this would be the choice of most English speaking people these days.

Let me point out that when I gave my answer I meant the spoken language. In (formal) writing the choice between **who** and **whom** would probably be in favour of **whom**.

Actually, **who**/**whom** may be simply omitted here.
"You're the one I want to be with" - that's what most people would say. :)

Comment: Are you sure about **who**? Shouldn't it be **whom** ?

Comment: @Cardinal Well, yes and no.. Have you ever heard people using **whom** in a phrase like this? If it were "with whom I want to be" then - no doubt. But "the one whom I want to be with"... In Charles Dickens novels, maybe..

Comment: @Cardinal I'm reading a rather long discussion on Language Usage on this "who vs whom" subject. From 2013. Cannot copy a link - android Stack Exchange app is deficient in many features, but you can easily find it...

Comment: “Know the rules well, so you can break them effectively.” 
― Dalai Lama XIV

Comment: @Rompey That's very true. I never advocate ignorance :)

Comment: @Cardinal The title is What's the rule for using "who" and "whom" correctly?. (from memory, so not verbatim but very close). Actually, happened to be verbatim ;)

Comment: If you are asked in a languages exam or test, which one would you use? Whom or who

Comment: @Cardinal I would choose *whom* because I know that this is formally correct. When sitting a test the main goal is to pass it and I'd use *whom* knowing that no one would fail me on this. Now (that I caught up on some sleep), you have convinced me that the word "perfectly" in my answer is a bit too much :) But, Cardinal, you ignored my question to you and just keep asking yours :)

Comment: What question ? I didn't notice any questions

Comment: "Have you ever heard people using whom in a phrase like this?" was the question a few comments above. And I meant - in a conversation, not in writing. (we'll soon be warned about making a long chat, so ... not that important really).